# How to modify a CSS pseudo class of an HTML element using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors

I have a code like this:

```
const myDiv = document.querySelector("#myDiv");
myDiv.addEventListener("click", fct_Div);

function fct_Div(ev) {
    console.log(ev);
    if (ev.altKey === true) {
        myDiv.style["background-color"] = "blue";
    }
}
```

with CSS:

```
        #myDiv {
            width: 400px;
            height: 400px;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
        #myDiv:hover {
            background-color: lightblue;
        }
```

I would like to access `#myDiv:hover` to change the background color.

Surely there is a way to do that?!

### Thanks for your time,

Andreï

Answer (score 0):

you can do like:

```
#myDiv {
        width: 400px;
        height: 400px;
        border: 1px solid black;#myDiv {
        --hover_background_color: lightblue;
    }

    }
    #myDiv:hover {
        background-color: var(--hover_background_color);
    }
```

then on js

```
document.querySelector("#myDiv").style.setProperty('--hover_background_color', "blue");
```